# explicit specialization syntax

Tags: c++

Is it

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T) {}

template <>
void foo(int) {}
```

explicit specialization or function overloading, and for the explicit initialization compiler want to see the following code?

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T) {}

template <>
void foo<int>(int) {}
```

I think that standard accepts both of these:

**ISO/IEC 14882:2011**

> ```
> 14.7.3 Explicit specialization [temp.expl.spec]
>
> 1 ...
>
> can be declared by a declaration introduced by template<>; that is:
> explicit-specialization:
> template < > declaration
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Either are allowed.  In the specialization

```
template <>
void foo(int) {}
```

the compiler infers the template argument `T = int` from the function arguments. From 14.7.3p10:

> A trailing *template-argument* can be left unspecified in the *template-id* naming an explicit function template specialization provided it can be deduced from the function argument type.

The example given involves a deduction from a class template, but it's just as applicable to deduction from a type used directly:

```
template<class T> class Array { /∗ ... ∗/ };
template<class T> void sort(Array<T>& v);
// explicit specialization for sort(Array<int>&)
// with deduced template-argument of type int
template<> void sort(Array<int>&);
```